# GD Star Rating WordPress Plugin Not Working

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have GD Star Rating WordPress Plugin. It is Working on admin side properly. But not displaying stars on frontend.

For example it returning 500 Internal Server Error on these pages 
http://novelsnippet.com/main/wp-content/plugins/gd-star-rating/gfx.php?value=5&set=oxygen&size=20&max=5

But the about file working on my another site properly.
http://metroui.org/wp-content/plugins/gd-star-rating/gfx.php?value=5&set=oxygen&size=20&max=5

While working on that issue i found something
A simple php page http://novelsnippet.com/main/test.php is working here and other folder too.
But not working inside all the folders of wp-content.

For example http://novelsnippet.com/main/wp-content/test.php

Comment: I already tried by increasing memory_limit and disabling all other plugins. But still having the error

Comment: Might be a permissions or htaccess issue.

Comment: same error even after removing htaccess. No permission problem i think. Because it already have 777 and still website is working fine. theme is loading from inside wp-content without any problems

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me:

Go to Settings and disable loading the CSS externally - many providers block external file inclusion for security reasons.

Worked for me, hope it works for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

At last we got solution from hosting provider. They fixed it now. They said he needed to whitelist a rule your script was running into.